# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '0001.png'

Tags: python-3.x

For some reason I'm having trouble running my code and throwing me an error

`logo = Image.open("0001.png")`

Then the error is this
`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '0001.png'`

Comment: Could you show me the folder structure including that image file?

Comment: We'll need to know more about your environment (cwd, directory structure, etc). have you tried using an absolute path instead of a relative?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.